# Regex to match a string containing 14 digits and 1 character at any position

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that matches a string of 15 characters where 14 of them are digits and 1 is a character.  The character can be in any position of the string.

I have the following long regex:

```
^.\d{14}|\d{1}.\d{13}|\d{2}.\d{12}|\d{3}.\d{11}|\d{4}.\d{10}|\d{5}.\d{9}|\d{6}.\d{8}|\d{7}.\d{7}|\d{8}.\d{6}|\d{9}.\d{5}|\d{10}.\d{4}|\d{11}.\d{3}|\d{12}.\d{2}|\d{13}.\d{1}|\d{14}.$
```

Can it be simplified?

Here is a sample match: `1000-1234567890`

Comment: It depends on where you are using the regex. In Go (RE2), you can't do otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?=^.{15}$)\d{0,14}\D\d{0,14}$`

First check the string is 15 characters long, then has 0-14 digits, one non-digit, then 0-14 digits.
This isn't exactly the same as the original regex, which allows 15 digits in a row.  To get that, simply change `\D` to `.`

Answer (score 0):

We can use a lookaround trick here:

```
^(?!(?:.*\D){2})(?=.{15}$)\d*\D\d*$
```

This regex pattern says to match:

- `^` from the start of the string
- `(?!(?:.*\D){2})` assert that 2 or more non digits do NOT occur (implying at most 1 occurs)
- `(?=.{15}$)` assert length is 15 characaters
- `\d*\D\d*` then a non digit surrounded, possibly, on either side by numbers
- `$` end of the string

Comment: `(?!.*\D.*\D)` is redundant. With `^\d*\D\d*$`, you can't have two `\D`s.